# Which for loop is better?

Tags: c, performance, memory-access

The below question was asked in Microsoft placement test. I cannot figure out which one will be better. Can somebody help me?

code 1:

```
int MAX=1000;
int a[MAX][MAX];
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    for(j=0;j<MAX;j++)
        a[j][i]=i*j;
```

code 2:

```
int MAX=1000;
int a[MAX][MAX];
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    for(j=0;j<MAX;j++)
        a[i][j]=i*j;
```

Which is correct?

1. code 1 is faster
2. code 2 is faster
3. both are same in RISC architecture
4. both are about same

Comment: Fix the code, you probably meant something along the lines of:
  a[i][j] = i * j;

Comment: I am sorry for the bug. Fixed it.

Comment: They access memory in a different pattern. Think about caches. Or try it.

Comment: Note: this is not actually an algorithm question.  It is more about language-specific details of data structure implementation.

Comment: Please do not tag spam, pick a language and stick with it

Comment: @Mgetz I added the language tags, because I couldn't tell which laguage the question was actually for.  However, AFAIK, the answer happens to be the same for all three of those languages.

Comment: @RBarryYoung That wasn't a helpful action, rolled back!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, my changes are technically correct.  My previous comment explains why.  If you disagree, discuss it here, on chat or on meta first, don't just rollback someone else's edits without giving a valid reason.

Comment: @Mgetz per your suggestion, I have reduced the tags to a single language.

Comment: Please choose the correct language. The code above is not C++; C++ requires constant array bounds. The code above uses a VLA, which is introduced in C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in how they access memory. Your array is laid out like this:

```
row 0 - 1000 integers
row 1 - 1000 integers
etc.
```

Now, your first loop accesses `a[0][0]`, then `a[1][0]`, etc. So it's going to locate row 0, then find column 0, and update it. Then it has to locate row 1, find column 0 in that row, and access it. So you end up accessing memory all over the place--essentially randomly. That's bad for the CPU cache because it has to reload with every memory access.

Your second loop accesses `a[0][0]`, then `a[0][1]`, then `a[0][2]`, etc. So it locates row 0, then it accesses the columns in sequence. This is *good* for the processor cache, and will execute faster because it doesn't have to reload as often.

Comment: This is not a jagged array, it is a simple 2D array which will be continuous in memory. EDIT: ok, my bad, it depends on the language. In C/C++ it will be continuous, not sure about managed languages.

Comment: @bialpio: That's going to depend on the language/runtime. But I get your point. I'll adjust.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. Just another question, wouldn't it be stored as a contiguous block of row*column size?

Comment: Your answer is still valid, basically the code that does not jump around the memory will potentially be faster.

Comment: @user: That depends on the language/runtime. In C#, the `a[][]` is not necessarily contiguous in memory. A two-dimensional array, `a[,]` *is* contiguous in memory. I don't recall how C and C++ lay out such arrays.

Comment: FYI, as noted below, this is not just an effect on CPU caches, it affects virtual memory management as well (and when it does, the hit is much larger than the CPU cache misses).

Comment: You made a typo: `a[0][0], a[1][0]...` in the first case.

Answer (score 3):

Code 2 can potentially be faster, assuming that you are using C/C++. C/C++ stores the arrays in row-major order, which means that the variations in rightmost dimensions give the least variation in memory addresses. Thanks to that, the CPU caching can help with performance of the code, and you will not have to worry about page faults (code 2 accesses the memory addresses in monotonic order so once the program is done reading one of the pages containing data, it will not have to look at that page anymore).

Comment: +1: FYI, it is not just CPU caches, virtual memory management (i.e. Page Faulting) is affected by this also.